# Bind a socket using public ip so can accessed using telnet

Tags: ios, c, sockets

I am creating a socket using

```
int listenfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

int b = bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
```

On telnet my local IP is working good, but I'm not able to connect using my public IP. I also tried

```
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("public.ip");
```

and it gives `-1` on bind with error.

```
Can't assign requested address
```

Is there a possibility to connect a socket using my public IP?

Comment: Is your public IP address being assigned to an interface of your machine or just to a router your machine is connected to?

Comment: Assigned to a router.

Comment: You can only bind to IP-addresses local to the machine you are doing the bind on, which the IP-address your router gets assigned obviously isn't.

Comment: Just for knowledge, how P2P connection works? What i am trying to achieve is to connect two devices using sockets. Currently working with iPhones. Is there any way to communicate between them otherwise Apple's GameKit

Comment: To connect devices which are located behind NAT-routers (NAT --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) you might like to read up on STUN/TUN concepts/services: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to connect a socket using my public ip

No, not if its assigned to a router which sits between the public net and your machine, but to you machine itself, at least not without additional efforts.

You might like to read about the concepts of [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN).